# Remove the blue when item is selected/clicked in android

Tags: android

I'm trying to remove the blue highlighted box I get when I click on an item.

This is my code

```
<item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/message_to_new_color"/>


<item android:state_activated="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/message_to_new_color"
    />

<item android:drawable="@drawable/message_to"/>
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: I don't see any `blue highlighted box` in the XML code you posted. Could you make it clear in your question?

Comment: its the default when an item is clicked - thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Hi I fixed this by using the below on my listview - hope it helps someone

```
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
```